# CodeIgniter - adding comments to a post

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I'd like some help please. I have a post page that has the full post and below the post a small form for adding comments. The uri of the post page is: site/posts/1, so it is in posts controller, and the form action is `form_open(site_url('comments/add/'.$post->post_id))`.

This is my add() function inside comments controller:

```
public function add($post_id){
    // if nothing posted redirect
    if (!$this->input->post()) {
        redirect(site_url());
    }

    // TODO: save comment in database
    $result = $this->comment_model->add($post_id);
    if ($result !== false) {
        redirect('posts/'.$post_id);
    }

    // TODO:load the view if required
}
```

and this is the add() function inside the comment model

```
public function add($post_id){
    $post_data = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
        'comment'   => $this->input->post('comment')
    );

    if ($this->validate($post_data)) {

        $this->db->insert('comments', $post_data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is if the $result = $this->comment_model->add($post_id); fails the validation to display the validation errors in my post view, else insert the comment and redirect to the same post page (site/posts/1).

The problem is that when I hit submit the form action goes in the comments/add/1, as expected, but doesn't do any these above.

Any ideas how can I fix this??

**EDIT**
I did a small change to the code without the 'confusing' validate() function. Maybe this is more helpful.

Comment controller:

```
 public function add($post_id){
    // if nothing posted redirect
    if (!$this->input->post()) {
        redirect(site_url());
    }

    // TODO: save comment in database
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->comment_model->rules);
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
    echo "Ok! TODO save the comment.";
   // $this->comment_model->add($post_id);
   // redirect('posts/'.$post_id);
  } else {
      echo "Validation Failed! TODO: show validation errors!";
  }

    // TODO:load the view if required
}
```

Comment model:

```
 public function add($post_id){
    $post_data = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
        'comment'   => $this->input->post('comment')
    );

        $this->db->insert('comments', $post_data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: where is your `function validate()` ?

Comment: Yes, this function performs validation. It is inside MY_Model See: https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model/blob/master/core/MY_Model.php

Comment: When you submit the form, did it go inside the `if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { ... }` statement?

Comment: Yes, if i submit correct the form it goes inside the if statement, otherwise it goes inside the else.. the problem is that i can't figure out how to display the validation errors on the post page (in my example: site/posts/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need away of passing `validation_errors()` back to your `Posts` controller. At the minute, when you perform the redirect in your `add` function (when the validation fails), you loose the validation errors thrown.

I would consider using `flashdata` (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) to pass a success/error message from your `Comments` controller back to your `Posts` controller. Something similar to the below:

**Comments Controller:**

```
public function add($post_id) {
    // if nothing posted redirect
    if (!$this->input->post()) {
        redirect(site_url());
    }

    // TODO: save comment in database
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->comment_model->rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        // Store the success message in flash data
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Ok! TODO save the comment.');
        // Redirect back to posts page
        redirect('posts/'.$post_id, 'refresh');
    } else {
        // Store the error message in flash data
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', validation_errors());
        // Redirect back to posts page
        redirect('posts/'.$post_id, 'refresh');
    }
}
```

**Posts Controller:**

```
public function index($post_id) {
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $this->load->view('posts', $this->data);
}
```

**Posts View:**

```
echo $message;
```

Might not be perfect but hope it helps...

Comment: True! With the redirect the validation_errors() are lost, so I guess the best way is to store them in session flashdata and get them back. However if there's an other better way I'd be grateful if you or someone else post it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I also keep the post values of each field if the validation fails? Can I also aply (with the validation errors too) something like this: $this->session->flashdata('post_values', $this->input->post())??

Comment: Yes. Exactly that!! That way you'll be passing back any errors encountered, plus the POST'ed data. Again...might not be perfect but does the job!!

Comment: yes but can i store both validation errors and post values in flashdata?? I'm not sure if I can store too many things

Comment: Yes. You can store both in flashdata and this works well if you are storing a reasonably small amount of things in flashdata.

By default, flashdata works with cookies and cookies are of limited size.

If the amount of data you are wanting to store exceeds this limit, then the easy way to prevent this is to use database based sessions which you can enable via the following item in your config.php file:

$config['sess_use_database']   = TRUE;